# Installing the SFGUI with Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libraries, sfml

I've been trying to install SFGUI library with Cmake tool with instructions given here: [SFGUI Install Tutorial](http://sfgui.sfml-dev.de/p/docs/guide/installing) . Still got many problems in major with Cmake, which couldn't find few files from SFGUI directory, for example 
`CMake Error: The source "D:/SFGUI-master/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "D:/SFGUI-0.3.0/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.` 
Restarting didn't help. Could anyone write how to install this in simple steps? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

cmake is telling you that the files it has generated in it's cache from a previous run don't match the source files you are currently using. I would imagine that you ran cmake, then switched git branches or tags and tried to run cmake again. You can just `rm -r CMakeFiles` in your build directory to remove the cache. Then you should be able to run cmake again without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It moved a little bit, but stopped actually at error:

`CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake:306 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
  SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/admin/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/sfml1/sfml1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

To be honest, I will write down steps I did: 1.Configured SFML in VS15 in Windows 8.1  2. I installed the newswet version of CMake 3. Installed also newest SFGUI from Github. 4.In Cmake GUI as a build I choose my project in VS and as a source - SFGUI directory. 5.In CMake Configure and there are the errors. Did I missed something?